# I detect some hacking attempts against my Webapp. What now?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, web-applications

I have a Tomcat webapp that does a lot of processing against the URL of every request that it receives. Most of them are perfect, but I'm beginning to see some things that are clearly feeble attempts at hacking (e.g. references to cgi-bin, wp-admin, etc.). I've also noticed some weird JS in the user agent for some reason (seems like a bizarre place to put it).

I can easily detect this and I return a 400 with a string saying that hacking was detected and your IP address is being logged. I'm guessing that no one ever sees my message.

Anyway, I was wondering if anything else can be done. Is a 400 the right code to send back? I've also been doing some reverse lookups on the IP address I get. Most are traceable to places in Eastern Europe, but I've also  seen some coming from Amazon AWS.

All of this is happening in real time, so if there was some sort of API to call to alert someone (AWS, CERT, ?????) I'd be happy to do it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how we can report things like this and if it's worth it?

Comment: Good luck with Eastern Europe and China. For AWS IPs, report to AWS. It is highly likely the AWS instance's security was compromised and the hacker is using the AWS instance to launch DDoS attacks.

Comment: Block the IP address at the firewall and with a RemoteAddress valve.

Comment: I realize that trying to deal with things from most of the world is going to be a pointless exercise. What I'm really after is something that I can automate so I'm not spending a lot of time doing this. Any ideas?

Comment: It's a fight against windmills. There are huge botnets that scan every IP and issue a broadside of requests targeting paths of known weak applications. If it is any comfort, it's neither personal nor targeted against your server. Be sure to update your tomcat frequently, that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One automated action you can take specific to AWS is to have your code create a new exclusion rule in your services AWS security group and exclude the IP address in question for a given amount of time. If you see regular hacking attempts from an AWS associated IP address you can report the EC2 abuse (which is more than likely the service being used) with the form located at https://aws.amazon.com/forms/report-abuse. It's important to note that you can't automate this process as AWS uses a captcha.

If it was a compromised EC2 service as [helloV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4237701/hellov) suggests then the account owner may not realise the issue until AWS contacts them and advised them of such. If it is an account which is deliberately being used as a hacking launch node then AWS will be able to check network traffic logs, identify the concerning traffic, and take action to close the account.

With regard to my comment on blocking the IP addresses at the security group level I would suggest no more than a 24 hour block as IP addresses are reassigned to new users constantly throughout the world and the last thing you want to do is restrict a new user to your service as a previous user has hacked your system from the IP address. Additionally blocking the IP at the security group level will result in the connection being denied and there is no way to customize the error message presented.